# grouping controls together in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a WPF app that needs to display a list of filenames and their corresponding controls. Right now I have a Grid with some columns (i.e. Column 1 is a `TextBlock` for a filename, column 2 is a `CheckBox` indicating if this file is chosen, etc., and there is one row for each filename.)

It works except when a control in row `i` is triggered, I have to search through the entire Grid to find other controls in row `i` and change them accordingly. Is there a *natural* way to group the controls in a single row together so that it's easy to find one given another?

Note: By *natural*, I mean something builtin WPF. Constructing a `UnionFind` for this wouldn't be considered natural.

Comment: the natural way is defining a `DataTemplate` for a file, this template contains a `TextBlock`, `CheckBox` and other controls that are `grouped` to represent a file and its various properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FI suggest to use an ItemsControl. Something like this

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="{Binding FileName}" />
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

With a `List<MyModel>` or `ObservableCollection<MyModel` of your model as the ItemsSource

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    // And so on ...
}
```